# CodeIgniter - Ensuring activerecord where statement has a criteria

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

Is the following code safe for deleting data?

```
public function remove($sc1_id = false)
{
    if(!$sc1_id) redirect('backend/sections/index');
    $sub_section_ids = $this->flatten($this->db->select('sc2_id')->from('sub_sections')->join('sections', 'sc2_sc1_id = sc1_id', 'INNER')->where('sc1_id', $sc1_id)->get()->result_array());
    if($sub_section_ids)
    {
        $this->db->where_in('s2l_sc2_id', $sub_section_ids);
        $this->db->delete('sub_section_prod_link');
    }

    $this->db->where('sc1_id', $sc1_id);
    $this->db->delete('sections');

    $this->db->where('sc2_sc1_id', $sc1_id);
    $this->db->delete('sub_sections');

    redirect('backend/be_sections/index');
}
```

I want to make sure that the where statements are being fullfilled.  In testing, data has been wiped, so perhaps `$sc1_id` was truey, yet still not making a condition on the where statement, or perhaps I need to `flush_cache()` or `reset_query()` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I would add, it's a transaction statement. You're using more than one table for the delete process, if one of then fails you can't go back. So:

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

//your statements here

//if something goes wrong, just undo
if($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
//if everything is ok, proceed
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
    redirect('to_somewhere');
}
```

Comment: Can you edit the answer to check if `$this->db->delete('sections');` affects more than 1 row? If so, then rollback?  I know you can do `affected_rows` in CI, but wasn't sure how to tie in with your very good suggestions of rollback.  Will accept your answer if so :).

Comment: Right after you execute your query, check `if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 1)` if so then call `$this->db->trans_rollback();`, you don't need to wait for the `status === false` if you have another condition for validation.